# Changing from type T to type Observable<T> in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am triyng to use ngrx store and effects in my application. 
Until now I have used the type "Vehicle":

```
export class Vehicle {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  alarm: Alarms[];
}
```

and I have used a service to get data from my web api. I have later used this to create my vehiclelist.
Now I want to use NGRX and to do so I need to use the type

```
Observable<Vehicle[]>
```

My HTML code looked like this:

```
 <!-- list of vehicles -->
        <aside class="vehiclelist">
            <mat-nav-list matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
                <th mat-sort-header="timestamp">Latest alarm</th>
                <th mat-sort-header="status">Status</th>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let stuff of sortedVehicles" class="vehicles">
                    <span [ngClass]="getColors(stuff)">
                    </span>
                    <p matLine (click)="updateInfo(stuff.id)"> {{ stuff.name }} </p>
                    <button mat-icon-button id="btn" *ngIf='check(stuff.alarm)' matTooltip="{{stuff.alarm[tooltipIndex(stuff)]?.timestamp}} - {{stuff.alarm[tooltipIndex(stuff)]?.description}}">
                        <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </aside>
```

And now I have changed my ngFor to something like this:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let stuff of (vehicles$ | async)" class="vehicles">
```

This is all good, but I can no longer use my "stuff" in the parameters of my functions. Is there anything I can do so I can use "stuff" inside my (click) functions?

Comment: The `async` pipe will unwrap the `observable`, so `stuff` should be a single `Vehicle` object. You should still be able to use it.

Comment: I did try that before but it returned the following error: "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for VehiclelistComponenet, pipe 'AsyncPipe'. 
I wrote the following ----  <span [ngClass]="getColors(stuff | async)">

Comment: You don't need the `async` pipe a second time, you've already unwrapped it. You can just do `getColors(stuff)`

Comment: You're right! It is working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another quick question.. If I have used Vehicle[] in my helper functions, in my component, and used methods such as .length and so on... How do I convert my new vehicles$ which is of type Observable<Vehicle[]> to a vehicles, of type Vehicle[] in typescript?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to subscribe to the Observable if you want the Vehicle array, but bear in mind it will be asynchronous

Comment: Ahh okok. Is there any better way to do it? Because in the example above you helped me with, the data came from my component.html, so the "vehicles$ | async" did the trick.. 

https://i.gyazo.com/b801b876d4b8e1185eedf80d1d52b14b.png
I wish to do something like this.
I want my vehicleDetails to be a VehicleDetail[]. My vehicleDetails$ is an Observable<VehicleDetail[]>